# How do I analyze a notepad crash? (Windows7)

Tags: windows-7, crash, notepad

from time to time my notepad crashes for no apparent reason:

- I open the windows notepad editor
- I type in something
- After a while I try to save the file through crtl+s

That's when notepad "freezes", the "save"-dialogue doesn't come up, the window just gets "greyed out" and windows tells me that the task is not responding (and asks if I want to close it or wait). This happens irregularly and I wasn't able to duplicate the process yet.

I suspect some third party software that is tied into the system. I'm using several programs that change the file dialogues behaviour. I use cloud addons (google and owncould) that synchronise a local directory but I don't ever save any textfiles there. I also tested already if it gets hung up on a networkdrive or a external drive, but it goes correctly to the default path, if it doesn't find the "last save"-path. I usually have several editors open at the same time. If the error, occurs with one of them. the others work fine and let me save my text files correctly. I don't remember this problem happening with a different program, but I could be mistaken there. Also I think it happens only with new files, choosing to save to an existing file (that was opened into notepad) I don't recall having the problem although I don't know if it ever happens when I choose "save as".

Of course I can save my data by creating a memory dump and just restart the damn thing, but I was wondering if it is possible to analyse what the problem is maybe even revive the "frozen" notepad.

Any hints or ideas would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You could check with Process Monitor what’s accessed last before hanging.

Comment: when you see this freeze open taskmgr (if you open 32bit notepad open 32bit taskmgr "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Taskmgr.exe" otherwise the normal 64 bit taskmgr) select the hanging notepad.exe process do a rightclick in taskmgr and select create dump. Now use [DebugDiag2 analyzer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924) to analyze the hang dump.

Comment: @magicandre1981 great, I'll try that next time. I still have the dump I created with process explorer (sysinternal) will that work as well?

Comment: @DanielB thanks, is it possible to let process monitor only capture events that are related to notepad. Since the problem with notepad only occurs every once in a while I would like to just leave it open. PS. I don't mean using the filter to hide the other captures, I just want it to capture anything with notepad in the first place so I don't have to start it manually each time I save s.th. in notepad (otherwise process monitor will use up too many resources, if I just leave it running the whole time).

Comment: Since you only experience the issue on *File | Save*, and you have add-ons that modify the standard dialogues, stop using the third-party tool or try a different text editor, such as Notepad++, that might work with the tools.

Comment: yes, if you use a recent ProcessExplorer version it is ok. Very old versions create 64bit dumps of 32bit applications which causes debugging issues.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I got the error message "Lock at 0x004749e0 owned by thread 2 is Deadlocked with lock at ntdll!LdrpLoaderLock owned by thread 0" is there a way to resolve or further analyse this issue next time the same type of hangup occurs? Maybe just close the thread that causes the deadlock?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jasone/2014/11/12/what-is-a-deadlock/

Comment: @magicandre1981  I know what a deadlock is in general from my SQL-Knowledge. The interesting question is, what exactly do I have to do to resolve it. I either want to quit the "saving process" that started the freeze, or let it continue until the end. I don't get the necessary information through your link to work out a available solution, or maybe I just overlooked the relevant part.

Comment: link shows to analyze a hang dump to find the cause.

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks, I'll try to through it again then